# Как кроссбраузерно открыть и закрыть дропдаун у select на js?

Tags: javascript, html5

Делаю нечто вроде вебвизора в яндекс-метрике. html менять не могу, он в теории может быть с любого сайта, как и css. Поэтому открыть/закрыть нужно именно dropdown, подмена селекта и изменение size не подходят. В хроме более-менее получается. Как это сделать кроссбраузерно?

```js
var open=false;
function simulate_mousedown(el) {
 if (document.createEvent) {
  var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
  event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 2, select.offsetLeft, select.offsetTop, select.offsetLeft, select.offsetTop, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
 } else if (el.fireEvent) {
  el.fireEvent("onmousedown");
 }
}
function simulate_mouseup(el) {
 if (document.createEvent) {
  var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
  event.initMouseEvent('mouseup', true, true, window, 2, select.offsetLeft, select.offsetTop, select.offsetLeft, select.offsetTop, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
 } else if (el.fireEvent) {
  el.fireEvent("onmouseup");
 }
}
document.getElementById('b').onclick=function(e){ 
 open=!open;
 if(open)
 simulate_mousedown(document.getElementById('select'));
 else //????
 simulate_mouseup(document.getElementById('select'));
}
```

```html
<button id="b">Toggle</button>
<select id="select">
 <option selected disabled>0</option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А вы не пробовали симулировать клик по уже выбранному элементу option для закрытия select?

Comment: а что значит _закрыть_ селект? при blur - дропдаун автоматически закрывается

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Пробовал, не помогает. Ставил ему selected и пробовал по нему клик и mousedown (на селекте клик не работает, нужен именно mousedown

Comment: @Grundy у меня вот (в Chrome) что-то не хочет.. `document.getElementById('select').blur()` имеется в виду?

Comment: кстати говоря у меня приведенный сниппет работает: один раз нажали кнопку появился, второй раз - скрылся

Comment: в FF / OS X не работает пример и его [исходник](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10453874/556876) тоже не работает.

Comment: @Grundy Когда я задавал вопрос я еще не пробовал mouseup для закрытия. У меня теперь тоже работает, но только в хроме, а нужно чтоб везде работало (по возможности).

Comment: @Darth, если нужно просто выпадающий список закрыть - используй _blur_

Comment: @Grundy а раскрыть? `focus()`?

Comment: @Darth, не, с фокусом не работает

Comment: @Grundy с blur тоже.

Comment: https://www.zoonman.com/projects/combobox/ - как вариант.

Answer (score 5):

Стандартных методов для открытия и закрытия у элеменета `<select>` [нет](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).

Поэтому для надёжной кросс-браузерности надо подменять select.

Comment: +1 - полностью согласен. Для примера приведу select2, который мне лично нравится. select2 имеет open метод, который можно использовать, чтобы открыть dropdown menu (`.select2("open");`). См пример [здесь](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic)

Comment: ответ конечно имеет место быть (потому что отвечает на вопрос в заголовке), но мне не подходит. Я специально написал это в вопросе. Крайне желательно никак не изменять DOM, максимум атрибуты ставить (checked,selected) и value менять

Comment: @Darth: Подумайте о поддержке touch ввода, о разных web browser'ах и прочих проблемах. Факт, если нет стандарта, то проблемы запрограммированы. Необходимо или использовать специализированную JavaScript библиотеку или же отказаться от стандартного select'a и использовать лучшую алтернативу. Вы пробовали мучить пользвателя длинными select'aми? Это лишь один пример. Просто взгляните на примеры на https://select2.github.io/examples.html и будет ясно что он, практически всегда удобнее стандартного. Есть и алтернативы select2: скажем [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Выбор - дело вкуса.

Comment: @Oleg У меня нет доступа к html. Он в теории может быть с любого сайта, как и css. Делаю что-то вроде вебвизора в яндекс-метрике. Насчет touch-ввода это вы очень кстати мне напомнили) Подумаю о поддержке,спасибо

Comment: @Darth, так [вебвизор](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/webvisor/about-webvisor.xml) только записывает клики. Разве он воспроизводит их? Если да – надо подсмотреть у Яндекса, как они открывают селекты.